# Spherical Advection Discretization (boundary nodes)

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions, hyperbolic-pde, advection, conservation

Consider the spherical advection problem: describing the conservation of a property $u$ in a closed spherical domain.

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2u\ \boldsymbol{v} \right)=0
$$

In the domain $0<r<1,\ t\geq0$, with the following initial/boundary conditions:

$$
\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right|_{r=a}=0,
\\
u(r,t=0)=u_i
$$
Where $\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{v}(r,t)$ and $u_i$ are known. ($\boldsymbol{v}\leq0$). Other posts ([here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/can-the-advection-equation-with-variable-velocity-be-conservative), and [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/conservative-finite-difference-expression-for-the-advection-equation)) suggested discretizing the conservative form.
Forward explicit (downwind) discretization leads to:
$$
r\to i\Delta r,\ t\to n\Delta t,\ u(r,t)\to u_i^n
\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
\to
\frac{u^{n+1}_i-u^{n}_i}{\Delta t}
\\
\frac{\partial(r^2u\ \boldsymbol{v})}{\partial r}
\to
\frac{
((i+1)\Delta r)^2 u_{i+1}^n \boldsymbol{v}_{i+1}^n-
(i\Delta r)^2 u_{i}^n \boldsymbol{v}_{i}^n
}{\Delta r}
$$
And the equation becomes:
$$
\frac{u^{n+1}_i-u^{n}_i}{\Delta t}=
-\frac{1}{(i\Delta r)^2}
\frac{
((i+1)\Delta r)^2 u_{i+1}^n \boldsymbol{v}_{i+1}^n-
(i\Delta r)^2 u_{i}^n \boldsymbol{v}_{i}^n
}{\Delta r}
$$

My problems are:

- I cannot use this equation at $r=1$ (last node) because i have no boundary condition to fix the ghost node at $r=1+\Delta r$.
- I'm unsure how to write the equation at $r=0$. I can either use L'Hôpital to write 
  $$
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+
  \lim_{r\to0}\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2u\ \boldsymbol{v} \right)\right)
  =
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+
  \lim_{r\to0}\left(\frac{1}{2r}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^2}\left(r^2u\ \boldsymbol{v} \right)\right)
  =\\
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+
  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial r^3}\left(r^2u\ \boldsymbol{v} \right)
  =0
  $$
  And discretize the above or I can use the forward derivative and write
  $$
  \frac{u_1^{n}-u_0^{n}}{\Delta r}=0\therefore u_0^{n}=u_1^{n}
  $$

What is the best way to discretize the problem and how do I address the first and last nodes?

**Edit**:

I found another post ([here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/boundary-conditions-for-the-advection-equation-discretized-by-a-finite-differenc?rq=1)) with almost the same problem. One of the answers suggested an interpolation for the stencil at the last node, which i tried with unsuccessful results. The solution returns values greater than $1$ at $r=1$ and does not converge at all as the nodes increase (unstable).
The image below shows the solutions for 21, 51 and 101 spatial nodes. The CFL number is below $1$. Solution should stabilize at $0.91$, and be less than $1$ for every instant.

[image: results for 21/51/101 nodes]

Comment: In case anyone wants to look further into the origin of this problem, [this](https://pt.scribd.com/document/321966798/Drug-Delivery-Using-Stimuli-Responsive-Polymer-Gel-Spheres) is the article I am trying to solve numerically.

Comment: I'm confused.  With $\nu<0$, you have material flowing inward from the outside boundary, so your discretization is upwind-biased (not downwind), and you need a boundary condition at the outside of the sphere, which you haven't provided.  Furthermore, it seems intuitively like the exact solution should develop a singularity at the origin, since all the mass arrives there eventually.